# Passing a path that appears multiple times in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml that looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <doc>
        <header>A1</header>
        <body>
            <subject>B1</subject>
        </body>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <header>A2</header>
        <body>
            <subject>B2</subject>
        </body>
    </doc>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to pass the path of the header in the variable (specifically header=A1). But when I try to call this variable, I get a XRTreeFrag cannot be cast to org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet error message

Here's my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="path">
        <xsl:value-of select="/xml/doc[header='A1']"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <object>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path/body/subject" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Solution has been found (included a condition where path reference can be either header = A1 or header = A2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="path1" select="/xml/doc[header='A1']">
    <xsl:variable name="path2" select="/xml/doc[header='A2']">
    <xsl:variable name="condition" select="$path1" />   
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="$path1[$condition] | $path2[not($condition)]" />      

    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <object>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path/body/subject" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's your desired outcome XML?

Comment: Your variable contains the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the `doc` element. If you want it to contain a reference to the element, you need to use `<xsl:variable name="path" select="/xml/doc[header='A1']" />` - as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="/xml/doc[header='A1']" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <object>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path/body/subject" />
        </object>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The outcome is

```
<object>B1</object>
```

Comment: Thanks that works! What if I wanted to include an if condition to assign the path "/xml/doc[header='A1']" if the header is A1?

Comment: Figured it out. Figured out how to take care of the scenario mentioned in the comment above (see original post for solution)